# Implementing negative number validation for a windows form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, validation

I have this little code snippet i've been working on. What it does is it provides validation for numbers with more than 2 decimal places.

```
    private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int amount;
        if (int.TryParse(amountTextBox.Text, out amount))
        {
            wantedTextBox.Text = Currency_Exchange.exchangeCurrency((Currencies)currencyComboBox.SelectedIndex, (Currencies)wantedCurrencyComboBox.SelectedIndex, amount).ToString("0.00");                
            wantedCurrencyLable.Text = ((Currencies)wantedCurrencyComboBox.SelectedIndex).ToString();
            groupBox.Visible = true;
        }

        else {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid amount");
        }
```

Now i've realized too late that I should've implemented validation for negative numbers aswell. However the way i've set the code up makes that difficult. Someone suggested I declare the parse of the textbox as a boolean but that only caused more trouble. How could I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `TryParse` succeeds, the parsed value will be stored in `amount`, so use this to first make sure it's a *valid* number and then, if it is, that the amount is greater than or equal to 0:

```
if (int.TryParse(amountTextBox.Text, out amount) && amount >= 0)
```